# Checking if a file exists from stdin <

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, stdin

I'm trying to create validation on a Python script that should take a file from the commandline. Much like:

`./script.py < somefilename`

As you can see the filename could come without any sort of extension on it. This should also work on multiple platforms, preferably.

In terms of validation it should be able to hold lines of strings separated by a newline character `\n`.

This poses two problems that I can't really solve:

1. I want to ensure that the file is of a correct filetype (ie. can hold text)
2. Check so the file actually exists.

In my current form I use argparse to parse flags, but since the requirements have changed I need to use a more *dynamic* (they say), solution where I implement the `<` "piper". This is quite simple by using `stdin`.

But using `stdin` poses a problem as I can't verify that the file exists; a user might input `textfile` without a correct extension, which would display

> 'No such file or directory'

---

What I'd like to do is create a list of possible extensions that **could** hold text (like '.txt') and check if a file with that extension exists in case the inputted file doesn't exist in the current folder. Just to make it more robust...

This seems to be very difficult (if not impossible) when using stdin, as you can't properly interface with the filename on multiple platforms.

I've also tried using fileinput, but I can't use a `fileinput.filename()` until I'm already reading the file:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    print fileinput.filename()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can add some robust file validation on the above mentioned example (`./script.py < somefilename`)?

Is it even possible on multiple platforms?

Comment: If you run `./script < filename`, the script isn't dealing with the file at all. The shell is reading the file and passing the contents into the script. Making this work would be a shell problem, not a Python problem.

Comment: Right. I understand that. I was hoping to see if there were any modules that could be used to somehow allow me to interface with the name of the inputted filename. In your example get the `filename` and check if a file exists with possible extensions (for instance `filename.txt`).

Comment: When using `./script < filename` are you making it a requirement that `filename` will be residing in the same dir as `./script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest going back to `argparse` and checking for existence of input files. This function:

```
import os
def check_file(filename):
    possible_extensions = ('', '.txt', '.dat')
    for e in possible_extensions:
        if os.path.isfile(filename + e): 
            return filename + e
    else:
        return None
```

will return its argument if a file under that name exists, otherwise it will test possible extensions and return the first match, or return `None` if no match is found.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for your program to determine how it was called by the shell, so these two commands are indistinguishable from your program's perspective:

```
$ ./script.py < somefilename
```

and

```
$ cat somefilename | script.py
```

If file `somefilename` doesn't exist, the caller will get a shell error like `No such file or directory`, and `./script.py` won't be even called by the shell, so there's no chance for it to validate anything in principle.

If the goal you're trying to achieve is to validate your program's arguments, you can always provide **an additional** way for that by passing input file to it using `-i` switch: `./script.py -i somefilename`, and validate file `somefilename` for existence. In order to achieve the desired level of versatility, the program also may provide an option to be called without `-i` switch, assuming that the file should be read from the `stdin`.